# Is boundedness of a sequence in a metric space sufficient for the sequence to be cauchy?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

We know Cauchy sequence is a bounded so is boundedness of a sequence in a metric space sufficient for the sequence to be Cauchy ? Thank you for your help .

Comment: If $a_n=(-1)^n$ a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ with the Euclidean metric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO.
Consider the sequence $a_n = (-1)^n$ in $\mathbb{R}$. It is clearly a bounded sequence but not a Cauchy sequence for $\mathbb{R}$ is complete and $(a_n)$ is not convergent.

Answer (score 0):

Note that any metric space $(X, d)$ can be equipped with a bounded metric $d'$ which is topologically equivalent to $d$.

For example, you can define $$d'(x,y) = \frac{d(x,y)}{1 + d(x,y)}, \quad\forall x, y \in X$$

Now *every* sequence in $X$ is bounded with respect to $d'$.

If you assume that boundedness implies Cauchyness, then the above would imply that every sequence in $X$ is a Cauchy sequence with respect to $d'$. Assuming $X$ is a complete metric space, this would imply that every sequence in $X$ converges in the topology induced by $d$. You can easily find examples where this is not the case.